# Is there any way to check if a user is new in flutter firebase (A facebook user)?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm looking for a way to check if a user just registered or is just signing in and there is no obvious way to do that with firebase and flutter with facebook authentication

Comment: AuthResult has AdditionalUserInfo which has **isNewUser** boolean which gives you this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I found is to compare the `lastSignInTimestamp` and `creationTimestamp` in the [user's metadata](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUserMetadata-class.html). If they're the same or close to each other, this is likely the use's first sign in.

Comment: AuthResult has AdditionalUserInfo which has **isNewUser** boolean which gives you this information.

Comment: Thats was good but add one second or more to  tolerance it. https://i.imgur.com/RykGQIS.png

Comment: This approach is wrong since lastSignInTimestamp will not be updated if a user signs in & out and signs in again under 2 minutes. See the relative issue:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/662

Answer (score 2):

class `AuthResult` has `AdditionalUserInfo` which has **`isNewUser`** boolean which gives you this information.

- https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/AuthResult-class.html
- https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/AdditionalUserInfo-class.html

Comment: updated link: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/AdditionalUserInfo-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use the FlutterFire plugins found [here](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/flutter/plugins/).

Specifically, the authentication package will help you manage this:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth

This bit of code will let you know whether there is a currentUser or not. Something along these lines.

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
if (user != null) {
    _message = 'Successfully signed in, uid: ' + user.uid;
} else {
    _message = 'Sign in failed';
}
```

Specific credential authentication with Facebook/Firestore:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/src/auth_provider/facebook_auth_provider.dart

You need to have the Facebook SDK imported as well and pass the credential there. Firebase login/registration calls handle the rest and then pass back a Firebase user, which you can then use to store your own type of user if needed (which seems like what you are looking for).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that is not what I'm looking for , I want to add the user details to the firestore only one time and that is when the user is first registered . However, firebase_auth does not support such function or method and I cant find anything close to it

Comment: Keep in mind I want to authenticate using facebook and facebook function does not differentiate between signing up and signing in

Comment: @OmarEmam Of course it doesn't have a one time function to add custom user properties to the database, that is on you the developer. The SDK provides ways for you to authenticate with Firebase through Google, Facebook, Twitter, Github and other platforms. You need to look through the documentation or word your question properly.

The resources I have linked you provide enough information to prove what I'm talking about. I'm even editing my response to now link further cases of Facebook/Firebase integration.

Comment: Okay thank you , though I was just wondering if there is a function which can handle what I want in flutter similar to this one boolean isNewUser = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();

Comment: Your original question was modified and the other answer now reflects the answer to your new question. Seems you have what you need.